# Update no. of categories from list of div elements using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of categories as filter like shown below:

```
<div class='filterbox'>
    <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="English"> English(<span id='English'>0</span>)
    <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="Math"> Math(<span id='Math'>0</span>)
    <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="Chemistry"> Chemistry(<span id='Chemistry'>0</span>)
    <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="Geography"> Geography (<span id='Geography'>0</span>)
</div>
```

And I have display boxes like

```
<div class="boxcategory">
    <div id='box1'><div class='categoryClass hidden'>English</div></div>
    <div id='box2'><div class='categoryClass hidden'>English</div></div>
    <div id='box3'><div class='categoryClass hidden'>Math</div></div>
    <div id='box4'><div class='categoryClass hidden'>English</div></div>
    <div id='box5'><div class='categoryClass hidden'>Chemistry</div></div>
    <div id='box6'><div class='categoryClass hidden'>English</div></div>
    <div id='box7'><div class='categoryClass hidden'>Math</div></div>
    <div id='box8'><div class='categoryClass hidden'>Chemistry</div></div>
    <div id='box9'><div class='categoryClass hidden'>Geography</div></div>
</div>
```

Using jquery, I want to update the total no in filterbox span from the displayed categories inside boxcategory class. Please guide.

Comment: You should demonstrate you tried to find a solution before posting this question, otherwise it feels like I'd just be writing your code for you.

Comment: Please do not write my code... just few lines of jquery that updates the number of categories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

count up the subjects by how many .categoryClass elements there are with the subject as their text content

```
function count (text) {
  return $('.categoryClass').filter((i, el) => el.innerHTML === text).length;
}

for (let subject of ['English', 'Math', 'Chemistry', 'Geography']) {
  $(`#${subject}`).text(count(subject));
}
```

see: https://jsfiddle.net/9my7f4qo/

note: you dont need jquery for this. vanilla js: https://jsfiddle.net/9my7f4qo/1/

Comment: Realistically though you don't _need_ jQuery for anything. jQuery is just there to make it easier to get done.

Comment: that's the reason I give the non-jquery example: in this case the vanilla  version is "easier" in some ways, though that's just my opinion